# Is it possible to dump / intercept all HTTP requests sent from `system.net` without the use of Fiddler or Wireshark?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, wireshark, dump

I would like to see all web requests from .Net applications. By this, I mean requests sent from any .Net application on my entire PC, not just a specific project.

I tried seeing if I could modify the `system.dll`, but saw that this was not possible. If there is any possible solution, it would be amazing.

Applications like Wireshark or Fiddler may not be applicable due to the fact that some applications have protections against these HTTP debugging programs which I would like to avoid. If it's possible to dump this from memory or hooking to a system dependency such as `system.net.dll` then that would be good to know however I am currently not aware of something like this.

Comment: _"due to the fact that some applications have protections against these HTTP debugging programs"_ if they do, then maybe for a reason and you shouldmn't attempt this, neither. Also, Wireshark taps into the network stack. So that's as much as you can do without altering the application code itself. **In other words:** What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What I am trying to do is target .net applications specifically so, for example, say if i run an application that is supposedly going to download something when executed, I can see the exact URL that it requests to as the request function is called in memory

Comment: And why would you need that? Is the download not what you expect? Are you suspicious of a malicious download or something like that?

Comment: I would use it to reverse engineer specific programs or potentially malicious programs, yes.